# how use express to serve static .html files that contain handlebar templates?

Tags: express

I would like to have handlebars templates within .html files.  How do I config express to serve static HTML files, but first let my node.js code replace the handlebar templates in the .html file?

Comment: If there's data in your templates, then they aren't static.

Comment: have you see this https://medium.com/@contact_97709/how-to-replace-content-in-static-files-with-node-js-7f6739a06f0a ?